# Create Minecfaft Server on linux

Tags: java, linux, jvm

I am having an issue with "Create a new startup script (start.sh) in the server directory to launch the JAR:"
For creating the Minecraft server, I was following the tutorial and while I was copying the code

```
"java -Xms1G -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -jar spigot.jar"
```

it gave me an error "Unable to access jar file spigot.jar" But I already created the Prerequisites 1,2. How does that happen?

https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/spigot-installation/#linux

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because your question is not "Programming" related, it is more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [**Super User**](http://superuser.com/) or [**Unix & Linux**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). That said, make sure you have write permission in the folder and the run script is executable. When I did this for my kids a few years ago, it was just a straight forward - start the server and open a port in the firewall.

Comment: Hint: are you running this java command line in the same directory as  *spigot.jar*?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that even tough your script is correct, your spigot.jar inside of the server folder is named different than the file you are calling in the script.

so if your file is named:

```
spigot-12.2.2.jar
```

your script has to look like that:

```
java -Xms1G -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -jar spigot-12.2.2.jar
```

Also its very important that your script is executed in the same directory as the spigot.jar is located in.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few answers.First is that your jar files is named something like this: `spigot-1.12.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` and not just `spigot.jar`.You also need to have that file in the same directory the spigot jar is in.